# Adding table to ArcGIS MapServer so layers and tables can be associated?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, map-service, relates

I'd like to add tables to my MapServer. I want it to include both feature layers and tables which enables me to associate the layers with the relevant tables and retrieving the necessary fields of the tables. The resulting structure will be like the one in the following link;
http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Petroleum/KSPetro/MapServer

After clicking on the "tops" table, the relationship between the layers and the table "tops" can be seen. Though all the necessary tables and layers can be seen through ArcCatalog, it cannot be seen in the MapServer. After updating the ArcCatalog, The MapServer is reset.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What version of arcgis server are you running?  In the mxd you have published, have you set up a join or relate between the wells and the tops?

Answer (score 2):

Using `ArcCatalog` or `ArcMap` you can utilize the [Relationship Classes Toolset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004t00000006000000) to create the relationships and relationship rules that you describe.